# For two subgroups $H, N$ of a non-abelian group $G$, if $HN\cong H\rtimes_{\tt A} N$, can we deduct $H\cap N=1$ if we know $N \unlhd HN$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, semidirect-product, direct-product

Note: groups $N, H, G$ are all non-abelian.

This is what I've known:

> - If $NH\cong N\rtimes_{\tt A} H$ (which means $NH$ is also a group and ${\tt A}$ is a group action), then:
>
>   - $HN=NH$, criteria for the product of subgroup to become a subgroup
>   - the two statements below are equivalent:
>
>     1. elements of $NH$ can be represented uniquely as $nh$, where $(n,h)\in N\times H$;
>     2. $N\cap H=1$
>
> Now: if $N\cap H = 1$ is given, then
>
> - the two statements below are equivalent:
>
>   1. $N\trianglelefteq HN$
>   2. $nh=hn$

And I also know the 1st/2nd/3rd group isomorphism theorem, so please be free to refer them.

BTW, I have an idea but not sure it is correct: I draw
a picture to represent the 2nd group isomorphism theorem ($\tfrac{H}{H\cap N}\cong \tfrac{HN}{N}$
when $H\leq G$ and $N\trianglelefteq G$), which is shown below:

2nd group isomorphism theorem
[image]

As you can see: the box in the left represent the group $HN$, where the intersection of its bottom surface (which is $N$) and its right surface (which is $H$) is $H\cap N$.
Now: if we apply the canonical map $\pi: hn \mapsto hn(H\cap N)$ on the box on the left, we will obtain the plane on the right hand side, just like the box on the left is smashed to a $2$-dimensional plane.

Comment: Oh the `\normalgroup` control sequence should be " $\trianglelefteq$ " , sorry .

Comment: You've got the notation backwards. If $N$ is the normal subgroup, then you want to write $N\rtimes H$, not $H\rtimes N$. The key to remembering is that the normal subgroup must be at the vertex of the triangle, just as it is in the usual notation $N\triangleleft G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to *define* an (internal) semidirect product $K\cong X\rtimes Y$ (which is isomorphic to an external semidirect product) is that all of the following hold:

- $X\cap Y=1$,
- $X\unlhd K$, $Y\le K$, and
- $K=XY$.

Therefore, the answer must be "yes".

Comment: Okay .... seems like I ask a meaningless question . I wonder : if the hypothesis is $NH\cong N\times H$ , where $N\times H$ stands for the cartesian product for group $N$ and $H$ , then what would happen ?

Comment: Since each direct product is a semidirect product, @Chen_zy, we reach the same conclusion.

Comment: Really appreciate for your answer, I was confused by my homework ...

Comment: You're welcome, @Chen_zy.

Comment: I think I know what I really want to ask : if there exists an isomorphism between $NH$ and $N\times H$ ( where the operation over the set $N\times H$ **can be anything** , **not just the operation of the direct-product and the semidirect product** , i.e. $(n_1,h_1)(n_2,h_2)\mapsto \cdots $ ) and $N\trianglelefteq NH$ , is it possible to obtain $N\cap H=1$ ? If it is okay , I will consider create a new question about this .

Comment: That's an interesting question, @Chen_zy. By all means, yes, ask it in a new post. I'll think about it in the meantime.

Comment: Here is the new post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4490062/