# A question about the definition of semidirect product of groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, semidirect-product, direct-product

### Question

Given $N,H$ two subgroups of $G$ : if there exists an isomorphism between $NH$ and $N\times H$ (where the operation over the set $N\times H$ **can be anything, not just the operation of the direct product and the
semidirect product**, i.e., $(n_1,h_1)(n_2,h_2)\mapsto \cdots$ and $N\trianglelefteq NH$, is it possible to obtain $N\cap H=1$?

(PS: groups $N, H, G$ are all non-abelian.)

My main purpose is: since the definition of semi-direct product $K=X\rtimes Y$ of group $X$ and $Y$ is

- $K=XY$,
- $X\cap Y = 1$, and
- $X\trianglelefteq K$ and $Y\leq K$,

then for the reverse: given $XY\cong X\times Y$ where the operation over $X\times Y$ is uncertain, is it possible to obtain $X\cap Y=1$
by $X\trianglelefteq XY$?

### What I know so far:

You can find them in here:

[For two subgroups $H, N$ of a non-abelian group $G$, if $HN\cong H\rtimes_{\tt A} N$, can we deduct $H\cap N=1$ if we know $N \unlhd HN$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4489976/)

I'm the same person who asked that question.

Comment: I have corrected your definition of $X\rtimes Y$.

Comment: I just made some adjustment .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot conclude that $N\cap H=\{e\}$ in $G$, since you are allowing any operation on the underlying set $N\times H$.

Here is an example: take $G=F\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, where $F$ is the free group on two letters, $x$ and $y$. Let $N=\langle (x,0+2\mathbb{Z}),(y,0+2\mathbb{Z})\rangle$, and let $H=\langle (x,1+2\mathbb{Z}),(y,1+2\mathbb{Z})\rangle$. Their intersection is nontrivial, since it contains all elements of the form $(w,0+2\mathbb{Z})$, where $w$ is an element of $F$ that has an even number of letters. In addition, though it was not specified, $N$ is normal in $G$.

Now, $NH$ is countably infinite (it equals $G$), as is $N\times H$; thus, there exists a bijection $\psi\colon NH\to N\times H$. Fix that bijection, and define an operation $\circ$ on $N\times H$ by [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure):
$$(n_1,h_1)\circ (n_2,h_2) = \psi\big(\psi^{-1}(n_1,h_1)\cdot\psi^{-1}(n_2,h_2)\bigr).$$
Then $(N\times H,\circ)$ is a group, $\psi$ is an isomorphism between $NH$ and $N\times H$, but $N\cap H\neq\{e\}$.

---

If both $H$ and $N$ are **finite**, though, then since $|NH||N\cap H|=|N|\,|H|=|N\times H|$, the existence of any bijection between $NH$ and $N\times H$ implies that $|N\cap H|=1$.

---

I will note that the nonabelianness of $G$, $N$, $H$ is completely irrelevant. Not sure why you believe it matters. The real issue here is whether $NH$ can be bijected with $N\times H$ when $N\cap H\neq\{e\}$.

Comment: But the OP supposes $N, H, G$ are all non-abelian.

Comment: @Shaun: Since when is the free group of rank $2$ abelian? My $G$, $N$, and $H$ are nonabelian.

Comment: I mean $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is abelian  . . .

Comment: @Shaun: So what? None of $N$, $H$, or $G$ are abelian. Nonabelian groups may have abelian factors. In any case, that restriction is utterly artificial and irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Oh, *I see!* I'm sorry: I read your answer too quickly . . .

Comment: Okay ... I think my graph in here https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyfUq.jpg could be inappropriate ...

Comment: @Chen_zy To me, that picture says nothing. And the one on the right mixes objects that do not even live in the same group ($H\cap N$ is a subgroup of $G$, while all the other ones live in a quotient). I have no clue what it was you were trying to say or capture with the picture, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: every single point on the right plane stands for a coset of $H\cap N$ .

Comment: @Chen_zy: No. $H/H\cap N$ is not a coset of $H\cap N$, it is a subgroup of $NH/N\cap H$ (it can only be a single coset if $H=H\cap N$. None of the other four are single cosets. Again, I have no idea what you think that conveys, but to me both pictures are nonsensical.

Comment: the point of the right plane (bottom right corner) should be $\tfrac{H\cap N}{H\cap N}$ , I made a typo

Comment: $\tfrac{H}{H\cap N}$ is a line , not a point .

Comment: @Chen_zy: You have $HN/N\cap H$; not a coset; you have $H/N\cap H$; not a coset. Please don't spent effort trying to "explain" the picture to me, because it is obviously a lost cause.

Comment: okay ... I gave up this idea .

Comment: I wonder : is there any good way to understand this , from a geometrical perspective ...

Comment: @Chen_zy Since I have no idea what "this" or "geometrical perspective" mean to you, I think there is little point to posting such "I wonder..." musings as comments here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137682/discussion-between-chen-zy-and-arturo-magidin).

Comment: @Chen_zy Nope. Not interested.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance and rudeness , and really appreciate for your answer .